# iTerm2: how to return a split pane to a tab?

Tags: terminal, iterm2

When working with multiple tabs in fullscreen mode, I often split a iTerm pane by dragging an open iTerm tab to the active pane.[image]

However, once I split the pane, I cannot find a way to return the split pane back to a tab. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a different way to accomplish what I am seeking?

Answer (score 3):

Select "Move Session to Split Pane" in the context menu, then click the pane.
Now you can drag the title bar of the pane.

Although I don't understand why it works.

Comment: It works! This a great example of non-intuitive behavior. Neither it's documented...

Comment: For me, it moved it to a new window. After that, I used "merge all windows" to restore the session to a tab.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to do it by "Move Session to Window" on the pane with the session you want to keep; "New Tab" in the new window; drag the tab you want over to another window; then close the extra window.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is another option to [bring pane back into the window/tab](https://azaleasays.com/2014/03/05/iterm2-merge-a-pane-back-to-window-or-tab-bar/):

> The secret key combination to drag a pane back to a window or to the tab bar is `command + shift + option` while dragging the pane body(not its header!). View the screencast in the original post.